# Ionic Observable can't use data outside subscribe async/sync conflict

Tags: asynchronous, ionic-framework, synchronous, subscribe

I am searching google all day for this problem. I understand why it is not working, but i can't find any solution or other way to get it work. I need to get it working.

I have made my own API that is correctly working when I surf to the url I get a JSON document with values. But now I got the problem with Ionic Asynchronous and Synchronous problems.

**Api Service**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    public getUserById(id: string)
    {
        return this._http.get(`mysite`);
    }
```

**profile.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiService} from '../../services/ApiService';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class Profile{

  user : any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private api : ApiService) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.api.getUserById('test').subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data;
      console.log(this.user);
    });
    console.log(this.user);
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage');
    }
    }
```

you see two console.log(this.user), one inside the subscribe (this ons is working I see my JSON in the console). the second one outside the subscribe (this one gives a error undifined).

After searching on google I found this article [image: Why it is not working] that explains why it is not working. But I can't find any other solution on how to do it the correct way, because now I can't use {{user.name}} (for example) on my html.

My question is how should I work around this or how can you use API with Ionic.

Comment: WHat does {{user.name}} display in your html?

Comment: it gives me an error